OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError
I am using the index and batch size to extract a batch of data, and then calling the train_on_batch method to calculate the loss. However, the following error has occurred:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 labels=c.cluster(X, y=None, iter_max=1e4)

File d:\ML5\keras_sdec.py:405, in DeepEmbeddingClustering.cluster(self, X, y, tol, update_interval, iter_max, save_interval, **kwargs)
    401 self.DEC.loss = SDEC.sdec_loss(
    402     add_loss=SDEC.add_loss(self.encoder.predict(X_batch),
    403                            a_batch))
    404 # print(self.p.dtype)
--> 405 loss = self.DEC.train_on_batch(X_batch, p_batch)
    406 sys.stdout.write('Loss %f' % loss)
    407 index += 1

File d:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\tensorflow\trainer.py:540, in TensorFlowTrainer.train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, return_dict)
    537 def data():
    538     yield (x, y, sample_weight)
--> 540 logs = self.train_function(data())
    541 logs = tree.map_structure(lambda x: np.array(x), logs)
    542 if return_dict:

File d:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py:153, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    151 except Exception as e:
    152   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
--> 153   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
...
---> 28     self.name = name or auto_name(self.__class__.__name__)
     29     self.reduction = standardize_reduction(reduction)
     30     self.dtype = dtype or backend.floatx()

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: Using a symbolic `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. You can attempt the following resolutions to the problem: If you are running in Graph mode, use Eager execution mode or decorate this function with @tf.function. If you are using AutoGraph, you can try decorating this function with @tf.function. If that does not work, then you may be using an unsupported feature or your source code may not be visible to AutoGraph. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/g3doc/reference/limitations.md#access-to-source-code for more information.
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...

This is the code where I'm encountering the error.
else:
                X_batch=X[index*self.batch_size:(index+1) * self.batch_size]
                a_batch=a[index*self.batch_size:(index+1) * self.batch_size, index*self.batch_size:(index+1) * self.batch_size]
                p_batch=self.p
                p_batch=p_batch[index*self.batch_size:(index+1) * self.batch_size]
                
                self.DEC.loss = SDEC.sdec_loss(
                    add_loss=SDEC.add_loss(self.encoder.predict(X_batch),
                                           a_batch))
                # print(self.p.dtype)
                loss = self.DEC.train_on_batch(X_batch, p_batch)
                sys.stdout.write('Loss %f' % loss)
                index += 1


Hi @ro may,Before executing the code make sure that eager execution is enabled and if you want to run functions immediately without compiling a graph, you can write tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution() at the beginning the code.if still you are facing the issue please share your code Thank You.
